# GCP cloud load balancer mapping update causes downtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-load-balancer

I'm changing the origin in the mapping of a Global HTTP Cloud Load Balancer on GCP and after I see the notice that the update is applied there is a period of about 1 minute where the response is a 502 served by Google.

The GCP Load Balancer logs show these 502s and indicate a statusDetail of "failed_to_pick_backend". Most of the entries show a backendServiceName which is empty, which is expected for a bucket backend, but the last few 502s show the original backendServiceName before recovering.

The original origin is an external service and the new origin is a bucket. The bucket and its backend service were there hours before the mapping change was made and both are healthy.

After that minute of 502s it started serving from the bucket normally with no errors and no action I took.

Is there a way avoid the 502s during the update?

Comment: AFAIK, no. Some changes to the load balancer cause reconfiguration which generates downtime. Schedule this type of work during off-peak hours.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'd never run into any configuration change on their load balancers cause downtime unless the configuration was wrong or a backend down/not ready. Is there something in the GCP documentation which say this and how this might be avoided altogether?

Comment: Having the same issue when updating the backends in a backend service. Kind of surprised since one of the main points (for us) with using a load balancer is to be able to dynamically move traffic around to *avoid* downtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you [create a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-load-balancer-backend-buckets#creating_buckets) to use as the backend for a HTTP(S) Load Balancing, it's recommended that you choose a multi-region bucket, which automatically replicates objects across multiple Google Cloud regions. This can improve the availability of your content and improve failure tolerance across your application.

Also it's recommended to review the [statusDetail HTTP failure messages](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#statusdetail_http_failure_messages) using the Cloud Logging advanced filter below, in order to get visibility of kind of error and the [potential causes and solutions](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs#unexplained_502_errors)

```
resource.type="http_load_balancer"
resource.labels.url_map_name="[URL Map]"
httpRequest.status=502
jsonPayload.statusDetails="[Failure Message]"
```

Comment: The statusDetail indicates failed_to_pick_backend, yet at the same time the backends continue serving on other paths which are configured separately in the router. This does not appear to be related with the availability of the backends themselves.

Comment: Thank you for your response, as per your comments it's recommended to open a case with GCP in order to review deeper this behavior I share the link https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers?hl=id